# fsync failed on Samba share, cannot write to anything

Tags: linux, samba, network-share, network-attached-storage, file-server

I have several Samba shares running on my Synology RackStation NAS server. Lets just call these Samba shares:

```
newton1
newton2
newton3
```

Each of the newtons is pointing towards a different RAID volume. `newton1` and `newton3` are working smoothly and accepting files in a timely way, as you would expect a Samba share to. But today I noticed that some users were having difficulty uploading files to `newton2` in particular.

On a Windows system; a user copied several files to `newton2`; the names and file sizes appeared, but these files had no contents.

I tried replicating this on my Linux machine too via Thunar and had similar results.

(Note that this user and I have permissions to write in these files/directories I'm talking about. `user=rwx, group=rwx, other=rx`)

I tried `touch test.txt` directly on `newton2` and the file appeared, but when I tried editing the contents in Vim I got this error:

```
"test.txt" E667: Fsync failed
```

A `du .` of `newton2` shows all of the recently uploaded files are null.

The RAID volume for `newton2` shows that only 6GB/30GB are used and the disks all appear healthy.

I'm really stumped at this point... Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being a Rack Station web interface option that wasn't immediately apparent. The [Shared Folder Quota](https://serverfault.com/q/961766/441445) was enabled at a quota size much less than what was already on this disk.

Any incoming data which would exceeded the quota gave a write error because no more data was allowed to be written to that disk.

Answer (score 0):

same thing is happening on a server of ours, client is a `Linux 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64` on a CentOS 7 server, mounted through `/etc/fstab`:

```
//server/sharedfolder /mnt/mountpoint  cifs    uid=5002,gid=5002,iocharset=utf8,credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0  0  0
```

as I am out of idea, I switch the mount to nfs