# What is a shared folder quota?

Tags: hard-drive, network-attached-storage, synology

I had this issue on my RackStation NAS the other day; I couldn't write anything to a volume I had created (let's call it `newton2`). I looked at the RackStation console and unchecked  this "Enable shared folder quota" box pictured below.

Enabled, but unable to write to `newton2`: [image: Shared folder quota checked]

Disabled, now I'm able to write to `newton2`: [image: Shared folder quota unchecked]

Can someone explain what this option means? Why was I unable to write to this volume while this option was enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's currently 6.56 TB used on your share. Therefore, it's already over the quota of 1 TB you were setting. If you had chosen e.g. 7 TB, there would have been some quota left. The rest is a dictionary definition.

> [**quota**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quota) (noun, ​ /ˈkwəʊtə/)
>
> a fixed limit on the amount of something that someone is allowed to
>   have or is expected to do